# django request absolute file path

Tags: django-request

using django requests, I am trying to get the absolute file path of original, uploaded file. The reason is I want to modify the original file so just the filename or some "media root" location just isn't enough.

I tried doing something like

```
request.FILES['file'].name
```

but that just gives me the name, not a path (neither absolute nor relative). google didn't really help, filenames are common, but path seems to be a special case. I hope it's even possible XP.

Thx in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

myfile = request.FILES['filename']

fs = FileSystemStorage()

filename = fs.save(myfile.name, myfile)

uploaded_file_url = fs.url(filename)

print(uploaded_file_url)

Also make sure you add the 'django.core.files.storage.FileSystemStorage' under Middleware_classes in settings.py file

Comment: sadly that just gives me the /media/<FILENAME> location, but not the original one.

Comment: also, I had to use FILES['file'] instead of FILES['filename]. using filename gave me a key-error. is that something I should worry about?

Comment: I would say, it is a bad idea if a user is permitted to access the actual location of the file. It is actually a security concern. Guess you will not be able to get that explicitly.

Comment: The reason you are getting /media/<FILENAME> is, django makes a copy of file that you upload into a media directory within your django application and then use that file for further processing. It doesn't alter any of the actual information of the file that is getting uploaded

Comment: FILES['filename'] is not an issue. It depends on what id we have used in our template. In your case I suppose you have user id="file" in your html

Comment: I know that django makes a copy and saves it to media-root. But in this special case, security aside, I really need to modify the original file, not the media-copy.